# Does Canada have similar tenure-track system as the USA?

Tags: professorship, united-states, tenure-track, canada

Does Canada have similar tenure-track system as the USA? Does it have around 6 years in a tenure-track position before getting tenure?

Answer (score 8):

[This study](http://www.malaspina.ca/integratedplanning/documents/OverviewofTPPoliciesinCanada.pdf) reviewed tenure-track positions across Canada. The time range from first probationary appointment to tenure is 3 to 7 years, with an average of 5 to 6 years.

Simon Fraser University's [tenure track policy](http://www.sfu.ca/policies/gazette/academic/a11-01_new.html) states that professors and associate professors shall be considered for tenure no later than the 4th year of the appointment, with options for early consideration or extensions. Assistant professors are considered for tenure no later than the 6th year of the appointment, with automatic promotion to Associate Professor if tenure is granted.